Can Olivetti mode do smart line breaks?
I am using olivetti in conjunction with modes that have some kind of markup. In particular, Org mode. (But this could apply to LaTex, for example.)
A markup, such as the inline "code" emphasis ("~") surrounds some text.
I would like olivtti to not do normal pseudo-breaking in that piece of text. When it won't fit within the line, it should break before it (start a new line for the emphasized text).
Is there a way to do that sort of thing?
